# Anonymous users can only see site if "SitePages/Home.aspx" is in URL

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-foundation, anonymous-authentication

I have a public-facing SharePoint Foundation 2010 site managed by a hosting company, so I don't have access to the 14 hive, web.config, Central Administration, etc. The site is a standard Team Site, so my home page URL resolves to /SitePages/Home.aspx.

I wanted to keep anonymous users from seeing All Site Content, etc. so I changed anonymous access from "Entire Web Site" Web to "Lists and Libraries", and gave anonymous users View Items access to all lists on the home page. If I open the page as "www.mysite.com/SitePages/Home.aspx", I can see everything. However, if I just type in "www.mysite.com", I get prompted for a log in. When anonymous users had access to "Entire Web Site", everything worked fine (except, of course, for them being able to see All Site Content.

What is the correct way to set up anonymous access for a SharePoint Foundation 2010 site?

Answer (score 1):

The login issue you are facing might be due to either the master page, page layout, or any content that is not checked in and published. Publish it and verify again.

There are also licensing issues which you would like to check before implementing SharePoint Foundation for public facing sites. Its not the same way as it goes for MOSS or WSS. Please check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511952/sharepoint-2010-foundation-licenses/3511977#3511977

Comment: I'll take a look, but that would probably mean an anonymous user couldn't see SitePages/Home.aspx either. Thanks.

Also, since I am using a hosted SharePoint site, do I need to worry about licensing? That's the host's concern, not mine.

Comment: Normally, if the welcome page is configured to SitePages/Home.aspx in the Site settings, even though you type "www.mysite.com" it should lead you to "www.mysite.com/SitePages/Home.aspx". Its kind of wierd in this case. Just try out the different options and do let me know.  The licensing part was added as an info for anyone who checks this post in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

While you don't have access to run commands on the server, the hosting company does and should support this.

stsadm -o activatefeature -url  -filename ViewFormPagesLockDown\feature.xml

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263468(office.12).aspx#section6
http://sharepointsharpener.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/viewformpageslockdown-does-not-kick-in/

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this, unfortunately that command only works for SharePoint Server 2010, not SharePoint Foundation 2010.